# In ASP.NET Web API, how to view the TraceRecord Details on a Built-in Page Nicely?

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, asp.net-web-api, trace

I've enabled tracing for my Web API application by creating a new Trace Writter which just logs the details in a file:

```
public class MyTraceWriter : ITraceWriter
{
    private readonly ILog _log;
    public MyTraceWriter(ILog log)
    {
        _log = log;
    }

    public void Trace(HttpRequestMessage request, string category, TraceLevel level, Action<TraceRecord> traceAction)
    {
        var traceRecord = new TraceRecord(request, category, level);
        traceAction(traceRecord);
        _log.Info(GetDetails(traceRecord));
    }

    private string GetDetails(TraceRecord traceRecord)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendFormat("\r\n\t{0} {1}\r\n\tCategory={2}, Level={3}, Kind={4}\r\n\tOperator:{5}, Operation: {6}",
                traceRecord.Request.Method,
                traceRecord.Request.RequestUri,
                traceRecord.Category,
                traceRecord.Level,
                traceRecord.Kind,
                traceRecord.Operator,
                traceRecord.Operation);

        if (traceRecord.Exception != null)
        {
            sb.AppendFormat("\r\n\tException : {0}", traceRecord.Exception.GetBaseException().Message);
        }
        else if (traceRecord.Message != null)
        {
            sb.AppendFormat("\r\n\tMessage : {0}", traceRecord.Message);
        }
        sb.AppendLine();
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Then registering my class in the Global.ascx:

```
config.Services.Replace(typeof(ITraceWriter),
                    new MyTraceWriter(LogManager.GetLogger("Tracing")));
```

I'm just wondering is there any built-in feature/tool/page that I can use/monitor to view the details of the tracing?

if possible, I'd like to avoid creating my own custom database table and page.

Comment: If you're only wanting to trace while debugging (ie, on your local machine), you can just trace out to a Visual Studio window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could alternatively install the "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Tracing" nuget package and then call `config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();` in your `WebApiConfig.cs`. This extension registers the `SystemDiagnosticsTraceWriter` for you.

You could also register an EventLog trace listener to write events to the EventLog, in which case you can use the EventViewer to view the data.

Example:

`<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="false" indentsize="4">
      <listeners>
        <add name="myListener"
          type="System.Diagnostics.EventLogTraceListener"
          initializeData="TraceListenerLog" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>`